# spring data JPA searching ignoring words order

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using the named method `dao.findByNameContains("hotel sheraton")`, I can get a list of hotels whose name includes `hotel sheraton`. But if a hotel's name is `sheraton hotel`, it will not return that hotel.

So I'd like to know how to search ignoring the words order if the string consisting of a list of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with a derived query (i.e. a query that is derived from the method name).

Probably the best approach is to use [`Specification`s as described in the linked article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

You can then have a method that turns a list of `String`s into a `Specification` that is a combination of Like-Specifications:

```java
public MySpecifications {

    public static Specification<???> nameContains(String namePart) {

        return new Specification<Customer> {

             public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                 return cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + namePart + "%");
             }
        };
    }

    public static Specification<???> nameContainsAny(Collection<String> nameParts) {

        Specification spec = Specification.where();

        for (String namePart : nameParts) {
            spec = spec.or(nameContains(String namePart)
        }

        return spec;
    }
}
```

*Note: mistakes in the code are intended as an exercise for the reader.*